# comparing in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have following knowledge base

```
team_name(1, conneticut).
team_name(2, duke).
team_name(3, memphis).
team_name(4, villanova).
team_name(5,gonzaga).

win_lose(1,22,2).
win_lose(2,24,1).
win_lose(3,23,2).
win_lose(4,20,2).
win_lose(5,21,3).

zone(west,5).
zone(south,3).
zone(east,1).
zone(east,2).
zone(east,4).
```

I want to write a query that allows the team with most wing play against the team with the least wins, which both are in the same zone, and the home team is the one with most wins

I have the following

```
canPlay(X,Y).                 Y can play X
canPlay(X,Y):-zone(zone(X)=:=Y).        Y can play X, if Y zone == X
```

it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. You're trying to pair up the best scoring team with the worst scoring team, but only within the same zone. This is how I would approach it:

```
canPlay(X, Y) :-
  team_name(XId, X), team_name(YId, Y),    % let's get team X and team Y
  X \= Y,                                  % make sure they aren't the same
  zone(Zone, XId), zone(Zone, YId).        % but make sure they are in the same zone
```

This is a good first stab but it's going to generate all the combinations, not just the ones where the two teams are appropriately matched by wins.

```
?- setof(X-Y, canPlay(X, Y), Pairings).
Pairings = [conneticut-duke, conneticut-villanova, duke-conneticut, 
            duke-villanova, villanova-conneticut, villanova-duke].
```

I don't fully understand the rest of your requirements, but hopefully this is enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: I understand what  you have done, and it makes more sense to me. just one question how is this checking if the team with highest score of wins is playing with the team with the lowest score of wins from the same zone. 

connecticut shout be able to play villanova, but should not be able to play duke since villanova has lower number of wins then duke.

Comment: Did you read the answer? "This is a good first stab but it's going to generate all the combinations, not just the ones where the two teams are appropriately matched by wins."

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fit your requirements

```
canPlay(Home, Guest) :-
    % get different Zones
    setof(Zone, Team^zone(Zone, Team), Zones),

    % in a Zone
    member(Zone, Zones),

    % get ordered list
    setof(Win-Team, Lost^(zone(Zone, Team), win_lose(Team, Win, Lost)), Standings),

    % take first and last
    append([[_-HomeId],_,[_-GuestId]], Standings),

    team_name(HomeId, Home),
    team_name(GuestId, Guest).
```