# Pairing off teams

Tags: prolog

The database contains a list of teams and each of these teams are separated by location (West team, East team, etc). There are two types of facts to describe this. team(TeamNumber, Losses) and region(TeamNumber, Region). For example:

```
team(1, 10).
team(2, 11).
team(3, 12).
team(4, 13).

region(1, east).
region(2, west).
region(3, east).
region(4, southeast).
```

NOTE: The list of teams isn't always ordered from least losses to most losses.

I'm trying to pair off a list of teams together so that the team with the highest losses is paired off with the team with the lowest losses and then the team with the second highest losses is paired off with the team with the second least losses, and ecetera ecetera. The rule is, pairing off teams within same regions is a priority. In the example above, teams 3 and 1 would be paired off together because they're both East teams. Now, the remaining teams are teams 2 and 4. But because no other team is in their region, teams 2 and 4 are matched against each other.

Now, I'm thinking what function I can write to pair off the teams. I've already written a function to group up all the different teams within a region into a corresponding list. I've also written a function to get the minimum and the maximum (highest and lowest losses).

How can I write a function(s) to pair off all the teams within the same region, and then make a new list sticking all the remaining teams in that list?

Comment: I take it none of the answers on [this almost duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127792/comparing-in-prolog) were sufficient?

Comment: Yea, I took a look at it, but it doesn't tell me how I can pair off the teams according to the highest win/loss rule.

Comment: Isn't that what @CapelliC's `% take first and last` line does?

Comment: Oh, I must have missed his function there. But I don't even know what his `% take first and last` is doing exactly. Could you please explain? I think I'll close this question after..

Comment: It's a comment. The `append/3` line below is doing the actual work.

Comment: Yea I actually meant the append/3, I don't know what that's doing. I'm also not sure how that ^ operator works..

Comment: The ^ operator causes the variable to the left to be "existentially quantified" in the expression on the right. Basically it says, I don't want a choice point for different values of Lost. It's usually easy to tell if you need it, because `setof/3` will return more times than you want with lists smaller than what you want. It mostly comes up with `setof/3` and `bagof/3`. `findall/3` behaves as if every variable is existentially quantified, and it never produces more than one result.

Comment: The `append/2` is saying, "get me the first and last items in the list." It's a pretty clever trick. Try this out in your terminal: `append([[X],_,[Y]], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).` You should get back `X=1, Y=8`. The answer is also pattern matching on pairs separated by `-/2` but that's happening at another level, so to speak.

Comment: Hmm now that I really took a look at that question, I think mine is a little bit different. I want to keep matching the highest losses with the lowest losses, but in the link you referred me to, if I'm understanding the code correctly, they only matched the highest and the lowest wins once. I need to repeatedly match pairs for each region. Also, how will canPlay be recursively called until a region has one or no more teams? And what do I do with the situation that there is one more member left in a region? I think the answers on that page aren't sufficient now.

Comment: I think if you can identify all those problems and you actually want to learn Prolog, you should try taking that solution as a starting point rather than demanding a new whole cloth solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I've also written a function to get the minimum and the maximum (highest and lowest losses).

Prolog and other declarative languages differ from procedural languages in some surprising ways, and one of them is that frequently doing one little bit of the work in anticipation of reusing it from within some kind of looping construct is not exactly the right approach. This is more obviously true in SQL where you should always be dealing in terms of sets, but it also holds in Prolog where the few explicit looping constructs we have are not heavily employed.

The problem of matching low and high scoring teams in a procedural environment would be best solved by a process like this:

```
def match(teams):
  while we have teams:
    remove the lowest scoring team from teams
    remove the highest scoring team from teams
    save this pair
  return the list of pairs
```

A naive way to make this more functional would be to use recursion:

```
def match(teams):
  if teams is empty: return empty list
  otherwise:
    remove the lowest scoring team
    remove the highest scoring team
    return this pair appended to match(teams without these two items)
```

You could actually convert this to reasonable looking Prolog without a lot of effort:

```
match([], []).
match(Teams, [Lowest-Highest|Pairs]) :-
  lowest(Teams, Lowest),
  highest(Teams, Highest),
  select(Lowest, Teams, TeamsWithoutLowest),
  select(Highest, TeamsWithoutLowest, RemainingTeams),
  match(RemainingTeams, Pairs).
```

This is not likely to be efficient because there is a lot of repeated list scanning and a lot of list rebuilding going on within `select/3`, but it might be more declarative.

Another approach would be to get the list of teams sorted, and then fold it back on itself to get the lowest and highest paired. Visually:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3],  [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3],  [6, 5, 4]

[1,     2,     3]
[6,     5,     4]
-------------------
[1-6], [2-5], [3-4]
```

We can do this somewhat directly in Prolog, but first we need a way to pair off two lists:

```
pair_off([], _, []).
pair_off([L|Ls], [R|Rs], [L-R|Rest]) :- pair_off(Ls, Rs, Rest).
```

Then the algorithm goes to Prolog like this:

```
match_lowest_highest(SortedList, Pairs) :-
  length(SortedList, N2),
  N is N2 div 2,
  length(TopHalf, N),
  append(TopHalf, BottomHalf, SortedList),
  reverse(BottomHalf, BottomHalfFlipped),
  pair_off(TopHalf, BottomHalfFlipped, Pairs).
```

This still isn't terribly efficient, but the `reverse/2` builtin is probably using difference lists so it shouldn't be too expensive; by using `append/3` with an already-materialized list of unknowns we save a bunch of temporary list construction which would just be thrown away. So I would not expect this to be horribly inefficient, but I'm sure there are other ways that it could be done that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've given it a shot. I think that all_teams_paired/2 will provide a list of all teams paired as you described, and a leftover team (if there are an odd-number of teams).

```
% list of all regions
regions(Regions) :- 
    findall(Region, region(_, Region), UnsortedRegions),
    sort(UnsortedRegions, Regions).

% list of all teams in a region
teams_in_region(Region, Teams) :- findall(Team, (team(Team, _), region(Team, Region)), Teams).

% bottom team in a list
bottom_team(TeamList, BottomTeam) :-
    member(BottomTeam, TeamList),
    findall(Losses, (team(Team, Losses), member(Team, TeamList)), AllLosses),
    team(BottomTeam, Losses),
    min_member(Losses, AllLosses).

% top team in a list
top_team(TeamList, TopTeam) :-
    member(TopTeam, TeamList),
    findall(Losses, (member(Team, TeamList), team(Team, Losses)), AllLosses),
    team(TopTeam, Losses),
    max_member(Losses, AllLosses).

% teams are paired with the top loser playing the bottom loser and there can be a leftover
%  if there is an odd number of teams
paired_teams([], [], []).
paired_teams([LonelyTeam], [], [LonelyTeam]).
paired_teams(TeamList, PairedTeams, UnpairedTeam) :-
    top_team(TeamList, TopTeam),
    bottom_team(TeamList, BottomTeam),
    TopTeam \= BottomTeam,
    subtract(TeamList, [TopTeam, BottomTeam], RemainingTeams),
    paired_teams(RemainingTeams, RemainingPairedTeams, UnpairedTeam),
    append([TopTeam-BottomTeam], RemainingPairedTeams, PairedTeams).

% a list of regions has an associated list of paired teams and leftover teams
region_paired_teams([], [], []).
region_paired_teams(Regions, PairedTeams, UnpairedTeams) :-
    Regions = [Region|RemainingRegions],
    teams_in_region(Region, TeamList),
    paired_teams(TeamList, RegionPairedTeams, RegionUnpairedTeam),
    region_paired_teams(RemainingRegions, RemainingPairedTeams, RemainingUnpairedTeams),
    append(RegionPairedTeams, RemainingPairedTeams, PairedTeams),
    append(RegionUnpairedTeam, RemainingUnpairedTeams, UnpairedTeams).

% a list of all teams paired with priority given to region and a leftover team (if any)
all_teams_paired(TeamsPaired, Leftover) :-
    regions(Regions),
    region_paired_teams(Regions, RegionPairedTeams, UnpairedTeams),
    paired_teams(UnpairedTeams, NonRegionPairedTeams, Leftover),
    append(RegionPairedTeams, NonRegionPairedTeams, TeamsPaired).
```

Have I understood your requirements correctly?

Comment: +1. I have shown how I would approach the pairing off problem in my own answer below, which I thought you might find interesting.

Comment: Both of your suggestions are much nicer than my implementation above. I know you mention that the first one (the "match" predicate) wouldn't be as efficient but it does make for some very nice looking Prolog code!

Comment: I think nice looking code is very important! I believe one should try hard to sequester as much of the efficiency concern in small corners of the program so the bulk of it will still read well. But it does seem like the longer one uses Prolog the greater one's concern for efficiency seems to become.